# Updating database using PHP without empty values from HTML form

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to update my SQL db without empty values from my form.
That's what I've got:

```
if(isset($_POST['account_details_submit'])) { 
    $user_id = array_values($_SESSION['user_info'])[9];
    $edited = date('d.m.Y h:i a');
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_first_name']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_first_name'])) { $add .= " and `first_name` = '$_POST[account_details_first_name]'"; }
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_last_name']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_last_name'])) { $add .= " and `last_name` = '$_POST[account_details_last_name]'"; }
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_phone_number']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_phone_number'])) { $add .= " and `phone_number` = '$_POST[account_details_phone_number]'"; }
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_address_1']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_address_1'])) { $add .= " and `address_1` = '$_POST[account_details_address_1]'"; }
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_address_2']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_address_2'])) { $add .= " and `address_2` = '$_POST[account_details_address_2]'"; }
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_city']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_city'])) { $add .= " and `city` = '$_POST[account_details_city]'"; }
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_post_code']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_post_code'])) { $add .= " and `post_code` = '$_POST[account_details_post_code]'"; }
    if(isset($_POST['account_details_country']) and !empty($_POST['account_details_country'])) { $add .= " and `country` = '$_POST[account_details_country]'"; }

    $update = "UPDATE `users` SET `edited` = '$edited'".$add." WHERE `id` = '$user_id'";

    if ($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

The message is "Record updated successfully" but only one row that is updating is row called *edited* and it's always updated to 0

I'm open for other ways how to do it.

P.S I have tried to do it using array value but the result isn't what I wanted

Comment: Just a note, you don't need both `isset` and `!empty`. Empty also checks to see if it's set, so only `!empty` is needed.

Comment: What is the result when you `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: the SET assignment list should be separated by commas, not "AND"

Comment: @aynber I assume that's why the updated value is zero. It's interpreting all those ands as a boolean expression

Comment: plenty of possibilities for sql injection here - consider converting to use `prepared statements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, though this is not tested, would be to use an array of form field names and database column names to help build your sql dynamically in a much safer manner using a `prepared statement`

```
if( !empty( $_SESSION['user_info'] ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {

    $fields=array(
        'account_details_first_name'    =>  'first_name',
        'account_details_last_name'     =>  'last_name',
        'account_details_phone_number'  =>  'phone_number',
        'account_details_address_1'     =>  'address_1',
        'account_details_address_2'     =>  'address_2',
        'account_details_city'          =>  'city',
        'account_details_post_code'     =>  'post_code',
        'account_details_country'       =>  'country'
    );

    /* default variables... */
    $user_id = array_values( $_SESSION['user_info'] )[9];
    $edited = date('d.m.Y h:i a');

    /* placeholders used to generate sql statement */
    $params=array();
    $values=array();
    $types=array();

    /* 
        iterate through all submitted POST fields - 
        if they are not empty add them to the placeholders 
    */
    foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
        if( !empty( $value ) ){
            $params[]=sprintf( '`%s`=?', $fields[ $field ] );
            $values[]=$value;
            $types[]='s';
        }
    }
    /*
        add semi-static variables to placeholders too
    */
    $values[]=$user_id;
    $types[]='s';


    /* create a sql statement and the use that to create the `prepared statement` */
    $sql = sprintf( 'update `users` set %s where `id`=?', implode( ',', $params ) );
    #echo $sql;
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

    /* bind the types and assign variables with a SPLAT */
    $stmt->bind_param( implode('',$types), ...$values );
    $result=$stmt->execute();

    echo $result ? 'Record updated successfully' : 'Error updating record';
}
```

By `echo`ing out the SQL prior to any calls to `$db` I was able to generate the following SQL which looks fine for use in the `prepared statement`:

```
update `users` set `first_name`=?,`last_name`=?,`phone_number`=?,`address_1`=?,`address_2`=?,`city`=?,`post_code`=?,`country`=? where `id`=?
```

Without the schema and data I can test no further but looks OK. Time now for a glass of wine...

Comment: that's good to hear - wish I could have tested before posting! The only part I didn't incorporate was the `$edited` variable - but that would seem like a nonsense if the `user` table had a `timestamp` field set to update on edit etc.

Answer (score -5):

You need separate fields by ',' and not 'and', I recommend you use xss protected with the function htmlspecialchars, see [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php).
Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['account_details_submit'])) {
    $valuesToUpdate = [];
    $fields = [
        'first_name'   => 'account_details_first_name',
        'last_name'    => 'account_details_last_name',
        'phone_number' => 'account_details_phone_number',
        'address_1'    => 'account_details_address_1',
        'address_2'    => 'account_details_address_2',
        'city'         => 'account_details_city',
        'post_code'    => 'account_details_post_code',
        'country'      => 'account_details_country'
    ];

    foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
        $protectedFromXss = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST[$field]));        
        if ($protectedFromXss) {
            $valuesToUpdate[] = "$key = '$protectedFromXss'";
        }
    }

    if (count($valuesToUpdate)) {
        $values = ', ' . implode(', ', $valuesToUpdate);
    }

    $edited = date('d.m.Y h:i a');
    $user_id = array_values($_SESSION['user_info'])[9];
    $update = "UPDATE `users` SET `edited` = '{$edited}' {$values} WHERE `id` = '$user_id'";

    if ($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: XSS protection should be done on output, not when sent to the database. Database queries should be protected with prepared statements and parameter binding.

Comment: @Matheus you were right. I replaced "and" with "," and everything works. I didn't think about the simplest solution here. Thanks