# php mysql prepared statment dont update empty values

Tags: php, mysql

```
  include_once 'db.php';

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE companies SET name =?, imgname = ?, mime = ?, img = ?, details= ? WHERE id = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param("sssbsi", $name, $imgname, $type, $img, $details, $id);

      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $details = $_POST['details'];
      $imgData = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
      $imgname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
      $type = $_FILES['img']['type'];
      $img = base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($imgData)));
      $stmt->execute();


      if(!$stmt->execute() === TRUE) {
         die('falied:' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
      } else {
         echo "seccuess";
       }

       $stmt->close();
       $conn->close();
       }
```

Prevent form process from updating database with empty values from form input. update only coulmns that have value and not empty.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: It's not necessary to do `=== TRUE` on a function that returns a boolean. It's especially strange to see `if (!x === TRUE)`.

Comment: Note: This is what an ORM does for you. Have a look at [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/),  or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) for examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating database using PHP without empty values from HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326574/updating-database-using-php-without-empty-values-from-html-form)

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent empty entries from updating your database, right? In this case, just check if the fields are empty, then redirect the user to the page again, preventing this action from being performed.

```
<?php


include_once 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $details = $_POST['details'];
    $imgData = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $imgname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['img']['type'];
    $img = base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($imgData)));
    $stmt->execute();


    //Checks if the user did not type anything in any of the fields, then redirects to the home page
    if(empty($name) || empty($id) || empty($details) || empty($imgData) || empty($imgname) || empty($type) || empty($type) || empty($img)){
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }



    $sql = "UPDATE companies SET name = :name, imgname = :imgname, mime = :mime, img = :img, details = :details WHERE id = :id";
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array(
        ":name" => $name,
        ":imgname" => $imgname,
        ":mime" => $type,
        ":img" => $img,
        ":details" => $details,
        ":id" => $id
    ));


    if($result == false){
        echo "Failed!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Success!";
    }


    $conn->close();

}
```

Comment: i actually want  the database to  update even if there was an empty entry. but dont update the table colmuns if they have empty entry.